# what does | 0x01 do in C language?

Tags: c

I have seen something like this in some of my coworkers code today :

```
I2C1ADB1= (slave_read_address | 0x01);
```

What does this | 0x01 part do? Does it end 1 at the end of the bits?

Let's say I2C1ADB1=0b00000000. If I use above line, will the new I2C1ADB1 be 0b000000001? Will it also increase the bit count from 8 to 9?

Comment: '|' is bit-wise OR operator. It will not increase the bit count. It will just set the bit 0 to 1.

Comment: There's plenty of resources out there, here's one: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/#bitwise

Comment: Ask yourself: How *could* it increase the bit count?

Comment: google for 'set bit with mask'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'|' is bit-wise OR operator in C. It does bit-wise OR between two values and return the final value.

```
I2C1ADB1= (slave_read_address | 0x01);
```

Assume slave_read_address in binary is `0bxxxxxxxx` where each `x` is bit value `1` or `0`. Similarly, `0x01` in binary is `0x00000001`.

As you know OR will return `true (1)` if at least one of the value is `true (1)`. Otherwise returns `false (0)`.

So After the above C line, I2C1ADB1 will have `0bxxxxxxx1`.

The operator will not ADD bits. Usually '|' (OR) operator is used to set a particular set of bits without altering other bits.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `I2C1ADB1 = (slave_read_address | 0x01);` stores the value of `slave_read_address` into `I2C1ADB1`, forcing the low order bit to `1`.

Your interpretation is incorrect, the value is not shifted, no extra bit is *appended*. The lowest bit is **set** to `1`:

- `0` becomes `1`,
- `1` is unchanged,
- `2` becomes `3`,
- `3` does not change,
- `4` becomes `5`,
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because on the left you have a variable and on the right a constant the result is to set all the corresponding 1 bits from the constant in the variable. In this case you’re right: it sets the last bit. No bit count increase occur!

Comment: This phrasing can be misleading. The expression does not “set all the corresponding 1 bits… in the variable.” Nothing in the variable changes. Also, the fact there is a variable on the left and a constant on the right is irrelevant. The `|` operator takes the value of its left operand (regardless of whether it is a variable, a constant, or a complicated expression) and the value of its right operand (again regardless of what it is) and produces the bitwise OR of the two values.

Comment: my english is not the best. I guess a better formulation might be "the intention is to set all the corresponding 1 bits from the constant ...". It's not irrelevant that there is a constant and a variable because the constant signals intention: that one wants to set a certain bit, or a particular set of bits.